Minecraft Forge 1.8.9 - Need to create custom command arguments
ive been trying to make a custom command on forge 1.8.9, but I couldnt find any guide or ducumentation on how to create argumens for the commands, the thing I want to do is for example "/settext ExampleText", the "ExampleText" should be a String, if anyone knows a solution I would really appreciate it.
I tried searching for documentation, youtube videos but couldnt find anything

Arguments by default (if there are no overloads) - are of string type already.
@Override
public void processCommand(ICommandSender sender, String[] args) {
   if (args.length > 0) {
        sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("you have set the text: " + text));
   } else {
        sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("Usage: /settext <text>"));

   }
}

im wrote the code from this template:
public class SimpleCommands extends CommandBase {

    @Override
    public String getCommandName() {
        return "whatsup";
    }

    @Override
    public String getCommandUsage(ICommandSender sender) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void processCommand(ICommandSender sender, String[] args) throws CommandException {
        // This is where I want it to send something in chat.
    }
    
}



Helped me to get a general idea, but it seems the code seems to be missing the part where it gets the argument from chat, but still thanks for help

Does it get the args from chat straight from the "String[], args"? If yes im having an issue  with it not printing out just the String it was set to, but it displays for example if I set it to "Hello" it displays "Ljava.lang.String;@6bb18f20" instead of "Hello".

nvm, Solved it! It appears  I was doing " sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("you have set the text: " + args));", but I forgot the "[0]" after the args so the correct code is: " sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("you have set the text: " + args[0]));", thank you for help!
